# Centre dialog on the screen in eclipse e4 RCP application immediately when Part is activated

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, e4

I am opening a dialog when left Part in my Eclipse RCP application is Activated.
In Part's @PostConstruct method, I am registering IPartListner to EPartService.
Following code shows that  :

```java
 partService.addPartListener(new IPartListener() {

        @Override
        public void partActivated(MPart part) {
            if(part.getElementId().equals("left_part_id")) {
                SignInDialog dialog = new SignInDialog(shell, display, eventBroker);
                dialog.open();
            }
        }
    });
```

Where in The SignInDialog which extends the JFace Dialog, I am doing this :

```java
@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell newShell) {
    Monitor monitor = display.getPrimaryMonitor();
    Rectangle monitorRect = monitor.getBounds();
    int x = monitorRect.x + (monitorRect.width - 600) / 2;
    int y = monitorRect.y + (monitorRect.height - 360) / 2;
    newShell.setLocation(x, y);
    newShell.setText("Sign In");
    super.configureShell(newShell);
}

@Override
protected Point getInitialSize() {
    return new Point(600, 360);
}
```

Please note that left Part is always visible and bundled through Application.e4xmi. My problem is that as soon as the part gets activated the dialog is shown in LowerRight corner on the monitor. If same dialog is opened from a button click, it shows correctly at the centre. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `getInitialLocation` method to set the location of the dialog. The size set in `configureShell` is being overridden by the default `getInitialLocation`

```java
@Override
protected Point getInitialLocation(final Point initialSize)
{
  Display display = getShell().getDisplay();
  Monitor monitor = display.getPrimaryMonitor();
  Rectangle monitorRect = monitor.getBounds();
  int x = monitorRect.x + (monitorRect.width - 600) / 2;
  int y = monitorRect.y + (monitorRect.height - 360) / 2;

  return new Point(x, y);
}
```